# heroku postgres db not saving data in cloud

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, heroku, heroku-postgres

I created a heroku Spring-MVC project in Eclipse. By default a sample application was created with url /people and /people/add.
Eveyrthing works fine when I run the app on Tomcat7. When I try adding a person and fetch it from DB works fine.
But when I stop the app and restart the app on Tomcat, the /get request doesn't fetch any details. I have to add the user details again.
I feel heroku is saving the data in some local DB which is getting refreshed everytime I run the app.

I want to use the free heroku Postgres DB, where the data is saved in heroku cloud. Could anyone please let me know if this is expected.

Please let me know the changes I need to make if any
Thanks

Comment: Do you have H2 or another in memory database in your dependencies?